# Jetpack Compose LazyRow and LazyColumn for category section auto scrolling

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am trying to build a screen with two main items. One of them needs to be a horizontal scrolling component where I will have some categories placed, second one being a lazyColumn below which has a Title + some sub category tiles underneath (cards)

The behaviour i want to achieve is, whenever you click on one of the items on the LazyRow, the LazyColumn below scrolls to that section, and vice versa, when the LazyColumn is scrolled, the LazyRow reflects the section it was scrolled to.

I could achieve the first requirement of clicking an item on LazyRow and scrolling the LazyColumn by using a lazyListState, however, the other behaviour I can not achieve. Could use some ideas!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

onGloballyPositioned retrieves the position of your composable, you could use that to navigate to your content.

I wrote some code to demonstrate it if you think it's helpful.

```
val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
val scrollState = rememberScrollState()
var scrollDestination by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

Column(Modifier.verticalScroll(scrollState)) {
    LazyRow(modifier = Modifier.padding(6.dp)) {
        items(5) {
            Button(modifier = Modifier
                .padding(8.dp),
                onClick = {
                    scope.launch {
                        scrollState.animateScrollTo(scrollDestination.roundToInt())
                    }

                }) {
                Text(text = "Scroll")
            }
        }
    }


    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(1000.dp)) {
        drawRect(color = Color.Green, size = size)
    }


    Text(
        "Content",
        modifier = Modifier.onGloballyPositioned { position ->
            scrollDestination = position.positionInParent().y
        }
    )
    Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(500.dp)) {
        drawRect(color = Color.Red, size = size)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, i did learn a few things from it. Even though the scroll from row works for this one, I want to achieve a vice versa behaviour as well, for example: lets say i scroll the list, the row stays on top of the screen ( I did manage that of course) and the content shown on the screen switches the respective button in the row into a selected state. Like a category list where when you scroll, the row shows the current category displayed. Is it possible to achieve this?